# MACRO expansion to block of preprocessors

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, macros

I have following preprocessor (code) block in my project before each function definition to unclutter the logging Macro.

```
#ifdef FC_NAME
#undef FC_NAME
#endif

#define FC_NAME  "myFunctionName"
```

But this itself looks kind of cluttered.

So, I am looking at replacing this with something that looks simpler and tried this

```
#define REDEF_FC_NAME(funcName) #ifdef FC_NAME \
\                                 #undef FC_NAME \
\                               #endif \
\                               #define FC_NAME funcName \
```

But this gives error saying macro def within a macro. So, is there a way of achieving the same effect?

Comment: Seems like you want a pre-pre-processor... I don't think you can do that in C/C++.

Comment: You could include another file (or even yourself) conditionally.

Comment: @Mysticial yeah, something like that :)

Comment: @Mysticial: m4 is your friend. (Kind of.)

Comment: What's wrong with simply undefining FC_NAME unconditionally?

Comment: Hm, never mind, I think you can't make a macro that produces another macro definition. But check out Boost.preprocessor for some neat tricks.

Comment: @all, guys, got the answer, \_\_FUNCTION\_\_ is defined in visual studio and \_\_func\_\_ in gcc :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't do that with macros.

But:

In C++, every function has a predefined `__func__` variable.

GCC offers this as an extension to C, as I'm sure do many other compilers.  On Windows, there appears to be the `__FUNCTION__` macro (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: I want it on Windows (Visual C++) :(

Comment: @Microkernel: Then you should mention that in your question!

Comment: Useless fact:  `__func__` is actually a function-local variable, not a macro.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Useless, but interesting.  Thanks!